# По какому принципу верстаются такие макеты?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

[image: Не получается сделать эти блоки, как их верстать просто обьясните принцип пожалуйста]

Я не понимаю то ли их нужно в список, то ли div`ами. Причем никакой отзывчивости от них, потому что когда я накоадываю взади цвет он не отзвчивый он просто есть он не тянется.

Comment: Используйте CSS Grid

Comment: А возможно ли его сделать адаптивным?

Answer (score 0):

Используй grid сетку - она как раз для таких вещей и создана. Вот ссылка на очень понятную и информативную статью об этом https://html5book.ru/css-grid/ .
В крайнем случае можно прибегнуть к некому извращению и использовать обычные `div` с `position:absolute` и с значениями `top/left/right/bottom` , которые соответствуют макету, также задавать явно `width` и `height`. Но учитывай, что все эти `div` необходимо обернуть в контейнер с `position:relative`.

Comment: Спасибо много интересных мыслей мне подкинули, все попробую!

Comment: А возможно ли его сделать адаптивным?